# Boost spirit take away keyword and ignore skipper

Tags: c++, keyword, boost-spirit, identifier

This is a small part of a grammer using expressions.

```
 prefix =
     (lit(L"not") >> prefix) 
    |(lit('-') >> prefix)
    | postfix
    ;
```

Some way inside postfix I have *name_pure* to take an identifier ..

```
name_pure = lexeme[+(boost::spirit::standard_wide::alpha | '_') >> *(boost::spirit::standard_wide::alnum | '_')];
```

So far all is fine. Can write something like

```
a=not b
```

But if I start to use *not* as a name prefix like this one

```
a=not notvarname
```

I get a parser Output from the AST which look like this

```
a=not not varname
```

Which means the *not* is used as prefix rule and not as `Name` with the rule *Name_pure*.

From my point of view it looks like the Skipper is not involved correctly.

This is my Skipper

```
 template<typename Iterator>
  struct eol_skipper : public qi::grammar<Iterator> {

    eol_skipper() : eol_skipper::base_type(skip) 
    {

      using qi::eol;
      using qi::lit;
      using qi::char_;     
      skip = ascii::space -eol;
    }
    qi::rule<Iterator> skip;
  };
```

Answer (score 3):

Like last time, I don't think the skipper is your problem.

Assumptions about what the skipper does, perhaps.

1. `space - eol` is just `blank`.
2. lexemes do not skip (that's the definition): [Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965)
3. PEG grammars are greedy and left-to-right. So, you need to make sure you're on a word boundary if you want to avoid matching `"not"` inside a purename: [Prevent the Boost Spirit Symbol parser from accepting a keyword too early](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21960167/prevent-the-boost-spirit-symbol-parser-from-accepting-a-keyword-too-early/21960899#21960899) or [How to parse reserved words correctly in boost spirit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131162/how-to-parse-reserved-words-correctly-in-boost-spirit/20133011#20133011)

I'd write the rules a lot more self-descriptive (e.g. `eol_skipper` suggests it skips `eol`, but that's exactly what it DOESN'T skip?).

```
using Skipper = qi::blank_type;
```

Then, make your `identifier` rule (pure_name?) an implicit `lexeme` by just dropping the skipper from the declaration:

```
  private:
    qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::AssignmentStatement()> start;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::AssignmentStatement(), Skipper> assignment;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::Expr(), Skipper> expr;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::Negated(), Skipper> negation;
    // implicit lexemes
    qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::Identifier()> identifier;
```

Finally, use `!p` parser directive to assert that `not` matched on a keyword/identifier boundary:

```
    negation
        = lexeme [(lit("not") | '0') >> !(alnum|'_')] >> expr 
        ;
```

### Demo Time

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/16aba7bbfebc410a)</kbd>**

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

namespace Ast {
    using Identifier = std::string;
    struct Negated;

    using Expr = boost::variant<Identifier, boost::recursive_wrapper<Negated> >;

    struct Negated {
        Expr expr;
    };

    struct AssignmentStatement {
        Identifier lhs;
        Expr rhs;
    };
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::Negated, expr)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::AssignmentStatement, lhs, rhs)

template <typename Iterator> struct parser : qi::grammar<Iterator, Ast::AssignmentStatement()> {
    using Skipper = qi::blank_type;

    parser() : parser::base_type(start) {
        using namespace qi;

        start      = skip(blank) [ assignment ];

        assignment = identifier >> '=' >> expr;

        expr       = negation | identifier;

        negation
            = lexeme [(lit("not") | '0') >> !(alnum|'_')] >> expr 
            ;

        identifier = char_("a-zA-Z_") >> *char_("a-zA-Z0-9_");
        // or:
        identifier = raw [ +(alpha | '_') >> *(alnum | '_') ];

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((start)(expr)(assignment)(identifier)(negation))
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::AssignmentStatement()> start;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::AssignmentStatement(), Skipper> assignment;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::Expr(), Skipper> expr;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::Negated(), Skipper> negation;
    // implicit lexemes
    qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::Identifier()> identifier;
};

namespace Ast {
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Negated const& o)             { return os << "NOT[" << o.expr << "]"; } 
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, AssignmentStatement const& a) { return os << a.lhs << " = " << a.rhs; } 
}

int main() {
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    for (std::string const input : {
            "a=not _b",
            "a=not not_var_name",
        })
    {
        It f = input.begin(), l = input.end();

        Ast::AssignmentStatement assignment;
        if (parse(f, l, parser<It>{}, assignment))
            std::cout << "Parsed " << assignment << "\n";
        else
            std::cout << "Parse failed\n";

        if (f!=l)
            std::cout << "Remaining unparsed input: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Parsed a = NOT[_b]
Parsed a = NOT[not_var_name]
```

> **NOTE** how defining `BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG` also gives you debug output in case you wanted to troubleshoot your rules, next time:

```xml
<start>
  <try>a=not b</try>
  <assignment>
    <try>a=not b</try>
    <identifier>
      <try>a=not b</try>
      <success>=not b</success>
      <attributes>[[a]]</attributes>
    </identifier>
    <expr>
      <try>not b</try>
      <negation>
        <try>not b</try>
        <expr>
          <try> b</try>
          <negation>
            <try> b</try>
            <fail/>
          </negation>
          <identifier>
            <try>b</try>
            <success></success>
            <attributes>[[b]]</attributes>
          </identifier>
          <success></success>
          <attributes>[[b]]</attributes>
        </expr>
        <success></success>
        <attributes>[[[b]]]</attributes>
      </negation>
      <success></success>
      <attributes>[[[b]]]</attributes>
    </expr>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[[[a], [[b]]]]</attributes>
  </assignment>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[[[a], [[b]]]]</attributes>
</start>
Parsed a = NOT[b]
<start>
  <try>a=not notvarname</try>
  <assignment>
    <try>a=not notvarname</try>
    <identifier>
      <try>a=not notvarname</try>
      <success>=not notvarname</success>
      <attributes>[[a]]</attributes>
    </identifier>
    <expr>
      <try>not notvarname</try>
      <negation>
        <try>not notvarname</try>
        <expr>
          <try> notvarname</try>
          <negation>
            <try> notvarname</try>
            <fail/>
          </negation>
          <identifier>
            <try>notvarname</try>
            <success></success>
            <attributes>[[n, o, t, v, a, r, n, a, m, e]]</attributes>
          </identifier>
          <success></success>
          <attributes>[[n, o, t, v, a, r, n, a, m, e]]</attributes>
        </expr>
        <success></success>
        <attributes>[[[n, o, t, v, a, r, n, a, m, e]]]</attributes>
      </negation>
      <success></success>
      <attributes>[[[n, o, t, v, a, r, n, a, m, e]]]</attributes>
    </expr>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[[[a], [[n, o, t, v, a, r, n, a, m, e]]]]</attributes>
  </assignment>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[[[a], [[n, o, t, v, a, r, n, a, m, e]]]]</attributes>
</start>
Parsed a = NOT[notvarname]
```

Comment: i like the kw approache from the link. This fits into my grammer very nice. But it Crash on usage with an access violation. The hint inside the Code already state that there might by a Problem .. but can´t see which one


`template <std::size_t N> static auto kw(char const (&key)[N]) -> qi::rule<Iterator> {
      // qi::lit has problems with char arrays, use pointer instead.
      return qi::lit(key) >> !qi::alnum;
    }`

Comment: after some more test it seems that this Code run .. ok it makes no sense because the static inside is just once there .. anyway it shows that the first Version of "kw" has a Kind of lifetime Issue .. `template <std::size_t N> static qi::rule<Iterator> & kw(char const (&key)[N])
{ 
   static qi::rule<Iterator> rule=qi::lit(key) >> !qi::alnum; 
   return rule;
}`

Comment: @Markus what does all that have to do with the question or this answer?

Comment: in your anser on point 3 you gave me a link to this samples. And the kw template was one of them. Your Code demo Code works fine but using the "kw" seems to be more elegant ..

Comment: I just fixed the identifier rule here, please comment about problems with other answers at those answers, or post a separate question. Yes, `auto` has lifetime issues with expression templates (there's a dozen or so answers about that on SO). If this answer was at all helpful, please remember to vote.

Comment: You could, of course, ask me to show how I'd use another approach :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159643/discussion-between-markus-and-sehe).

Comment: Here's what I'd write in C++14 http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9054cab63670b0e
And c++11 could be like http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/173fe306aa64b139