# boost spirit wide char rule create null char´s

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

With this rule

```
name_valid %= (lexeme[+(boost::spirit::standard_wide::alpha | lit('_'))]);
```

of type

```
typedef qi::rule<Iterator, std::wstring()> name_valid;
```

Running in debug mode all is fine. *name_valid* contains the correct string. When going to release mode in VC2017 I got a NUL char on such inputs

```
Input  : a_b  
Output : a(NULL)b
```

I found out that I have to rewrite the rule like this. Can´t see a `lit` as wide char operation. Do I miss something here?

```
 name_valid %= +(boost::spirit::standard_wide::alpha | wide::char_(L'_'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i found out that i have to rewrite the rule like this

Well, if the goal was to match `'_'` as part of a name, then you NEED to write that anyway. Because `+(alpha | '_')` exposes an attribute which is the character sequence of all `alpha` characters, but not `'_'` since literals do not expose an attribute.

> Can´t see a lit as wide char operation.

That's `qi::lit(L'_')`

> Do i miss something here

What I *think* is happening is that `alpha|'_'` synthesizes an `optional<char>`. Apparently, the propagation rules are so relaxed that `optional<char>` can be assigned to `char` through its conversion-to-bool operation (resulting in a NUL characater). Wide characters have nothing to do with it:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/565f2804020ba7d6)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace enc = boost::spirit::standard;

int main() {
    std::string const input = "A.B";
    auto f = input.begin(), l = input.end();

    std::string output;
    if (qi::parse(f, l, +(enc::alpha | '.'), output)) {
        std::cout << "Parsed: '" << output << "'\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Failed\n";
    }

    if (f!=l)
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
}
```

Prints

```
00000000: 5061 7273 6564 3a20 2741 0042 270a       Parsed: 'A.B'.
```

---

### Testing The Hypothesis:

Splitting it up in separate rules makes it visible: **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2e097389258659e)</kbd>**

```
qi::rule<It, char()> c = enc::alpha | '.';
qi::rule<It, std::string()> s = +c;
BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((s)(c))
```

Prints

```
<s>
  <try>A.B</try>
  <c>
    <try>A.B</try>
    <success>.B</success>
    <attributes>[A]</attributes>
  </c>
  <c>
    <try>.B</try>
    <success>B</success>
    <attributes>[NUL]</attributes>
  </c>
  <c>
    <try>B</try>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[B]</attributes>
  </c>
  <c>
    <try></try>
    <fail/>
  </c>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[[A, NUL, B]]</attributes>
</s>
```

This highlights that the `char` exposed by `c` indeed becomes the NUL char. The following, however, makes clear that wasn't completely intentional:  **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dffc449d7a5737df)</kbd>**

```
qi::rule<It, boost::optional<char>()> c = enc::alpha | '.';
qi::rule<It, std::string()> s = +c;
BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((s)(c))
```

which will abort with an assertion:

```
sotest: /home/sehe/custom/boost_1_65_0/boost/optional/optional.hpp:1106: boost::optional::reference_const_type boost::optional<char>::get() const [T = char]: Assertion `this->is_initialized()' failed.
```

> Out of curiosity: this fixes it: **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28fe764fd684de91)</kbd>**
>
> ```
> qi::rule<It, std::string()> c = enc::alpha | '.';
> qi::rule<It, std::string()> s = +c;
> ```
>
> Prints
>
> ```
> Parsed: 'AB'
> ```
>
> fully as expected

### Summary

Automatic attribute propagation rules are powerful, but can be surprising.

Don't play fast and loose with attribute compatibility: say what you mean. In your case `alpha | char_('_')` is conceptually the only thing that SHOULD do what you expect.

Comment: After reading all that, go back to my [previous answer and see how I defined the `identifier` rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47444041/85371). That already showed you your error, even though your question wasn't about that at the time. Note also, the sample code gave you two variants :)